# How to customize cdk overlay pane?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat-menu and mat-select in different components. The issue I am facing is that when we set

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container .cdk-overlay-pane {
}
```

in both the component's css file, it conflict each other (Which is expected).
So is there a way to customize the overlay-pane in both components so that it doesn't affect the other component's style.

Answer (score 4):

#### Menu component

From Angular Material *v10*, we can use `MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` injection token. It has an option -  `overlayPanelClass: string | string[]`, which represents:

> the class or list of classes to be applied to the menu's overlay panel.

Use the following code at component or at module level:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'menu-overlay-pane' }
  }
]
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmjhh6

Docs:
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuDefaultOptions

#### Select component

From Angular Material *v11*, we can use `MAT_SELECT_CONFIG` injection token. It has an option -  `overlayPanelClass: string | string[]`, which represents:

> the class or list of classes to be applied to the menu's overlay panel.

Use the following code at component or at module level:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: MAT_SELECT_CONFIG,
    useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'select-overlay-pane' }
  }
]
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ig6y8v

Docs:
https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MAT_SELECT_CONFIG
https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectConfig

#### Autocomplete component

Use the following code at component or at module level:

```js
import { MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';

providers: [
  {
    provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'autcomplete-overlay-pane' }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to change things which are descendants of the overlay like `.mat-menu-content` but not to overlay itself.

Depending on what you are trying to style you may be able to do this way:

**app.component.scss**

```
::ng-deep .mat-menu-panel {
  background-color: unset;
}

::ng-deep .overlay-style-one .mat-menu-content {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

::ng-deep .overlay-style-two .mat-menu-content {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu1">Menu 1</button>
  <mat-menu #menu1="matMenu" class="overlay-style-one">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
</ng-container>

<ng-container>
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu2">Menu 2</button>
  <mat-menu #menu2="matMenu" class="overlay-style-two">
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 3</button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 4</button>
  </mat-menu>
</ng-container>
```

If you want to change the CSS of `.cdk-overlay-pane` itself, I can't see how I would do this. There is a single `div` with the `cdk-overlay-container` that's reused for all overlays and it's a direct child of the `body` element. There is [no parent selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) which if it existed could have helped here.

There is an [OverlayConfig](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#OverlayConfig) in the API but it seems to be for changing Overlays globally.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work! 
The mat-menu is kept inside a table with ng-container. So do I need to consider these as well?

Comment: @user1991 sorry, I hadn't considered the cdkOverlay itself. I've updated my answer. I've been able to style elements that are descendants of the overlay itself like `.mat-menu-content` but not conditionally change the overlay itself.

Comment: Much appeeciated Gilles!