# How to customize or apply another class with ".cdk-overlay-pane" for angular material mat-select | mat-dialog

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-select

I am using mat-select to display a list of options. So, when you click on the mat-select input filed, it shows a list of options using div with cdk-overlay-pane class.
I want to customize cdk-overlay-pane class. Using ::ng-deep I did this like,

```
  ::ng-deep {
    .cdk-overlay-pane {
      transform: translateX(-40px) translateY(-13px) !important;
    }
  }
```

& it works also, but it is affecting another cdk-overlay-pane.

Is there any way to give customClass to that div with cdk-overlay-pane ?

```
<div id="cdk-overlay-1" class="cdk-overlay-pane customClass" style="transform: translateX(-40px) translateY(-51px);">
```

so that only this div will be customized & it will not affect other divs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `MAT_SELECT_CONFIG` injection token . It has an option `overlayPanelClass: string | string[]`, which represents:

> the class or list of classes to be applied to the menu's overlay panel.

Shortly, use the following code at component or at module level:

```js
providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_SELECT_CONFIG,
      useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'customClass' }
    }
  ],
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxgonn

---

The `overlayPanelClass` option is available from **Angular Material v11.**

`MAT_SELECT_CONFIG` is docummented [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MAT_SELECT_CONFIG).
`MatSelectConfig` is docummented [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectConfig):

Comment: MAT_SELECT_CONFIG & MatSelectConfig are in the documentation, but they've not mentioned how to use them. So, it looks confusing for beginners. It'll be better if they give some examples also.

Comment: Thanks. The same method can be used for mat-menu as well. Just replace MAT_SELECT_CONFIG with MAT_MENU_DEFAULT_OPTIONS.

Comment: @DeepeshKumar, you're right. I've posted an answer about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679508/how-to-customize-cdk-overlay-pane/70076714#70076714

Comment: Does the datepicker has something like this? I guess not, because I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: @SzörényiÁdám, I didn't find anything in the docs, but I took a look in the code and I found that the datepicker overlay panel receives the following classes: `mat-datepicker-popup` or `mat-datepicker-dialog`: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/datepicker-base.ts#L649. Maybe you can use them

Comment: Or maybe you can use  the `panelClass` property for the `mat-datepicker` component. It will style the  `<mat-calendar>` node, that is placed inside the `cdk-overlay-pane`.

Comment: @andreivictor Thanks. I needed a custom class because I wanted to use the picker inside an ag-grid filter and cancelling the picker closed the filter (you can disable this behavior if you add a class to both the panel and the overlay div as well). I used a workaround now with native js and the open event of the datepicker. I hope in the future there will be a better solution.

Comment: I had a similar issue and this worked for me as posted.  in my scenario i needed to make a change to the cdk-overlay-pane without impacting any of the other controls.  In my scenario i was using

::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane.customClass {
  //Change cdk properties
}

Answer (score 3):

@andreivictor's answer didn't work for me. Because I'm using select inside the autocomplete. If you are using autocomplete you have to do like this;

```
import { MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
```

--

```
..
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: { overlayPanelClass: 'customClass' }
    }
  ],
..
```